# What is `exports.config` in protractor?

Tags: protractor

> ## Protractor config file#
>
> **What is `exports.config` in protractor?**

Comment: See  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Answer (score 5):

Do you say this: exports.config = { ... }

Is used for globals variables and configuation of your test.

For example:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",
  baseUrl: "localhost:8080"
}]
```

More: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md

Answer (score 1):

exports.config in Protractor is used to specify configuration in conf.js like below:

```
exports.config = {
  // The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  // define browser capabilities
  capabilities: {
     browserName: 'chrome',
     chromeOptions: {
        args: [
             '--disable-extensions',
            ]
    }
 },
  // Define which tests should execute.
  specs: ['test-spec.js']

 // set log level
 logLevel: 'verbose',
 // Enables colors for log output
 coloredLogs: true,
};
```

Default framework used is Jasmine, to run tests use below command

```
     protractor conf.js
```

Answer (score 0):

export.config{.....}

It is the place where we define /configure framework details, selenium details, Specs,Script timeouts, Onprepare functions, capabilities,reports and all generic stuffs.

As soon Run starts, protractor looks for this file first and tries to executes the stuffs here. 
for eg) initiating selenium web-driver instances,opening Browser etc.

EG)

```
    exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',      //framework Used
    seleniumPort: 4444,         // selenium port address
   //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    specs: ['./Spec/Master.spec.js'],  /*Spec -> consists of test suite/ test cases  */
allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {                   //jasmine framework details
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000,
    print: function() {}
},
capabilities:                  //Browser details against which test runs
    {
        'browserName' :'chrome',
        'chromeOptions' : {
            'args':['incognito','--start-maximized'],  /*this line is for maximize the window and incognito view */
            prefs: {
                'profile:managed_default_content_settings.notifications': 1
            }
        }

    },
      //before starting the 
      actual TC execution, setup the things we define here

   onPrepare: function (config_) {            
    require('./Data/waitReady.js');
    //browser.manage().window().maximize();

    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: false,
        savePath: './Reports/JunitXMLprotractor-result/',
        filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
    }));

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
            savePath: './Reports/Screenshots/',
            takeScreenshots: true,
            takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
            consolidateAll: true,
            showPassed: true,
            // filePrefix: sessionId + 'AutomationReport',
            filePrefix: 'AutomationReport',
            cleanDestination: true,
        })
    );


    global.isAngularSite = function(flag){
        browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = !flag;
    };
```